# multi condition in $match mongodb aggregate framework _ mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have multiple conditions for the query in my controller that I need path if exists.

condition 1 :

```
{ tags: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.tagId)}
```

condition 2:

```
{ reportedBy: { '$ne': req.user._id }} // if this video object reported dont show
```

condition 3:

```
{ owner: { '$ne': userblocks } } // userblocks is a array of objectIds
```

so this is my $match filter:

```
{
 '$match':
   _.isString(req.params.tagId) ?
   { tags: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.tagId), 
   reportedBy:{ '$ne': req.user._id}, owner: { '$ne': userblocks}}:
   { reportedBy:{ '$ne': req.user._id},owner: {'$ne': userblocks}}
},
```

I used **...** spread operator if **tagId**  passed to params.this condition works for tagId but other conditions are not working.

with @Anthony Winzlet hint I tried to :

```
{reportedBy:{ '$ne': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)},owner: {'$ne': userblocks}}
```

and **userblocks** is a list of objects, I checked the type of them and they are objects too.**so no need to cast them to objectIds.**

Comment: You need to cast your other id to mongoose objectId. Just you did with the `tagId`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet in my user blocks all of them are objects not string. let userblocks = [...req.user.blockedUser, ...req.user.blockedBy].map(blocks=>mongoose.Types.ObjectId(blocks));

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet and I tried this to: {reportedBy:{ '$ne': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)},owner: {'$ne': userblocks}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let $match = {
   reportedBy: { '$ne': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
   owner: { '$nin': userblocks } // $nin when comparing against array of object ids
},

if(_.isString(req.params.tagId)) {
   $match.tags = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.tagId)
}
```

Then just use `$match` in your `aggregation pipeline` or as part of whatever else parts of the pipeline you would have.

Things to note:

- When comparing to `_id` `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` function should be used.
- When comparing against an array `$in` or `$nin` are usually what you would want to use.
- It seems in your `_.isSting` check logic you had `reportedBy` and `owner` in both scenarios so it seems to me some refactoring would not hurt.

Comment: owner: {'$nin': userblocks} this works fine .but this is not working: reportedBy:{ '$ne': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)}